# The unit tests are not clear or not working for the functions I wrote

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, jasmine, karma-jasmine

These are the 2 functions in the "recipe.service.ts" file:

```
setRecipes(recipes: Recipe[]) {
    this.recipes = recipes;
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice());
}

getRecipes() {
    return this.recipes.slice();
}
```

These are the 2 tests I wrote for them:

This test is passing, but I do not know if I formatted the code properly. It does not seem to follow what I normally see in proper unit tests.

```
  it('should set the recipes', () => {
    service.recipesChanged.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("hello 2", data);
      expect(data[0].description).toBe('This is simply a test');
    });
  });
```

This test is failing and I am not sure why. The LOG says "LOG: 'hi', undefined" because it is not able to get recipes.

```
  it('should slice the copy on getRecipes', () => {
    recipeSpy.setRecipes.and.returnValue(of(mockRecipes));
    const recipe = service.getRecipes();
    console.log("hi", recipe);
    expect(recipe[0].description).toBe('This is simply a test');
  });
```

How should both these unit tests be set up for their functions?

Comment: could you add how `recipeSpy` is created?

Comment: @Andres2142   const recipeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('RecipeService',
    ['setRecipes', 'getRecipes'],
    {recipesChanged: of(mockRecipes), recipes: mockRecipes}
  );